# Getting the current directory, can I do it without knowing max buffer size?

Tags: c++, windows, directory

The syntax for getting the current directory in C++ is:

```
GetCurrentDirectory(DWORD nBufferLength, LPTSTR lpBuffer);
```

Is there no way to get the current directory without knowing a maximum buffer size?

I'm just afraid that if I put down a maximum length, someone will exceed it and my program will fail.

I can't use `argv[]` because I'm using Win32.

Comment: Isn't that something I define?  Or is that already defined for me?

Comment: It's already defined. It's the maximum length of a path, so it won't be returning anything with more characters than that. Of course, you can go the `std::vector` route, too, with passing null.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass NULL as the buffer pointer, and 0 as the buffer length, the function will return the necessary buffer size.

As [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) points out, this is covered in the
[the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: "If the buffer that is pointed to by `lpBuffer` is not large enough, the return value specifies the required size of the buffer, in characters, including the null-terminating character." -- [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)